# Calculate number of columns where a row value is same

Tags: php, mysql, repeat, multiple-columns, vote

I am doing the coding in `PHP 5.2.17`

I want to calculate the number of users whose value for the column named `vote` is `1`

There are 5 things to vote for
when a user votes of a image, the id of the image gets added to the vote (in the above case 1)

So I want to display the statistics **i.e.** the number of people that voted for images separately.

**i.e.** the value of the vote should be shown just next to the corresponding image.

help me with the MySQL code and PHP

I tried all types of combinations with count and couldn't get the required result!
this is my latest try

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT count(vote) as Users_who_voted_count FROM data WHERE vote='2'");

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
echo $res['Users_who_voted_count'];
window.jQuery
```

Comment: have you already tried anything?

Comment: then why didn't you put that into your question? how are we supposed to konow where your actual PROBLEM lies when you don't ask a real question?

Comment: the code belongs into your question... edit the question not the comment!

Comment: Okay question edited ..Please help

Answer (score 0):

First:
do NOT mix `mysqli` and `mysql` functions!

Look into the documentation of mysqli and try again.

Second:
Your mysql query should look like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as Users_who_voted_count,vote FROM data WHERE vote = '2' GROUP BY vote
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

this is the error message now

Comment: OKAy Thanks a lot for helping.. Someone just beat stackoverflow in answering my quesion